# Inputting data in SAS, reading multiple lines

Tags: input, sas, read-data

I get an error when I try reading the following data lines in SAS. Can you help pinpoint my error? Thank you.

```
    DATA VOA; 
   INPUT #1 Address 1-37 $ #2 City $ State $ Zip #3 Latitude Longitude; 
   datalines; 
   1675 C Street , Suite 201    
   Anchorage    AK  99501   
   61.205475    -149.886882
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention the error message.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the person who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406585/how-can-i-read-in-data-with-uneven-spacings)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `input #1 Address $ 1-37...`